# Can I find the amount of available IP addresses in an Azure subnet?

Tags: azure, powershell, subnet, vnet

I'm trying to find a way to list the amount of available IP addresses in an Azure vNet.
I know this is available in the GUI, as can be seen below:

[image]

Question is, can we have the same information in the Powershell Az module?

Thanks!

Eitan

Answer (score 2):

From what I've seen, there is no direct way to fetch the number of available IP addresses from a subnet address range.

However, its easy enough to use the following formula:

```
2 ^ (32 - netmask length) - number of reserved Azure IPs - number of already occupied IPs
```

So if you had a subnet address range such as `10.1.0.0/24`, and one IP was already being occupied by another device, this would calculate to:

```
(2 ^ (32 - 24)) - 5 - 1 => (2 ^ 8) - 6 => 256 - 6 => 250
```

Furthermore, with PowerShell we could put these steps into code like this:

```bsh
$resourceGroupName = "myResourceGroup"
$virtualNetworkName = "myResourceGroup-vnet"
$subnetName = "default"

$virtualNetwork = Get-AzVirtualNetwork `
    -Name $virtualNetworkName `
    -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName

$subnet = Get-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig `
    -VirtualNetwork $virtualNetwork `
    -Name $subnetName

$subnetMask = $subnet.AddressPrefix.Split("/")[1]

$netmaskLength = [Math]::Pow(2, 32 - [int]$subnetMask)

$availableIpAddresses = $netmaskLength - 5 - $subnet.IpConfigurations.Count

$availableIpAddresses
```

Reference for the above Az module Cmdlets:

- [`Get-AzVirtualNetwork`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/get-azvirtualnetwork?view=azps-4.6.1)
- [`Get-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/get-azvirtualnetworksubnetconfig?view=azps-4.6.1)

Additionally, have look at [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-faq#are-there-any-restrictions-on-using-ip-addresses-within-these-subnets) to see why Azure reserves 5 IP addresses specifically.

Comment: How to list the first available private IP of the subnet?

Answer (score 0):

I came across this [`solution`](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/b98im2/azure_find_out_how_many_ips_are_left_in_subnet/),

```
$TableProperties = @(
    @{Name="VNET" ; Expression={$VNET.Name}}
    "Name"
    "AddressPrefix"
    @{Name="IPsConfigured" ; Expression={$SubnetConfigured.Count}}
    @{Name="IPsLeft" ; Expression={$AvailableAddresses - $SubnetConfigured.Count}} 
)

$Subnet | 
    Select-Object $TableProperties | 
        Format-Table -Autosize
```